# Iterating through all values for a particular key, in order, for a LinkedHashMultiMap

Tags: java, guava

I would like to iterate through the values of a particular key for a `LinkedHashMultiMap<String,String>` (Guava), by insertion order.

Is this possible? And, if so, how?

Why a `LinkedHashMultiMap`? Well, my existing data structure was a `HashMultiMap` and I figured if I changed it to a `LinkedHashMultiMap`, that would be compatible with my existing code and I could iterate the values somehow.

But looking at the docs, I can't quite figure it out - that said, I'm new to the `LinkedHashMultiMap` class.

Comment: "Similarly, get, removeAll, and replaceValues return collections that iterate through the values in the order they were added." Where's the confusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Iteration in insertion order for `LinkedHashMultimap` [is a documented behavior](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/20.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html)

> Implementation of `Multimap` that does not allow duplicate key-value entries and that returns collections whose **iterators follow the ordering in which the data was added to the multimap**.

and will work out of the box, see [wiki page on `Multimap` implementations](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#implementations-1):

```
| Implementation       | Keys behave like... | Values behave like.. |
|:---------------------|:--------------------|:---------------------|
| LinkedHashMultimap** | LinkedHashMap       | LinkedHashSet        |

`**` `LinkedHashMultimap` preserves insertion order of entries,  
as well as the insertion order of keys, and the set of values associated with any one key.
```

Code example:

```
LinkedHashMultimap<String, String> m = LinkedHashMultimap.create();

m.put("a", "foo");
m.put("b", "bar");
m.put("a", "baz");

m.get("a").forEach(System.out::println); // outputs "foo" and "baz"
```

Comment: I think I was just confused with get() returning a Set and not a LinkedHashSet. I guess it was done this way to conform to an interface.

Comment: @ycomp It's not written in stone that `LinkedHashMultimap#get` will always return `LinkedHashSet`, so don't try to do any cast. What **is** guaranteed by contract is that returned `Set` will behave like LHS, which means insertion order is guaranteed.

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`get`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html#get(K)) and then iterate over the resulting `Set` in a for-each loop.

```
for (String value : multimap.get(key)) {

}
```

The iterator for the set will iterate in the order they were added to the `Multimap`, as specified by the [documentation](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/LinkedHashMultimap.html).

> Similarly, `get`, `removeAll`, and `replaceValues` return collections that iterate through the values in the order they were added.